# Pass a value from WP API do Vue href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, wordpress-rest-api, vue-directives

I'm trying to pass value from API to href but a run on error.

Here is code:

```
<a v-bind:href="'{{post.acf.link }}' ">See more</a>
```

My output is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Bpost.acf.link%20%7D%7D
```

Please somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
<a v-bind:href="post.acf.link">See more</a>
```